# Spring with Swing Integration Failed , java.awt.HeadlessException , BeanCreationException, BeanInstantiationException .SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, swing, spring-boot, exception, awt

I am not getting any error when I execute the following in Spring Tool Suite with tomcat server. But when I execute the same in external tomcat server by creating war I am getting following errors:

Error 1: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Error 2: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException

Error 3: Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException

**headless(false) didnt help me.**

MY main Class.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"service.my.rest.app"})

public class ConnectionTest extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
// This method will run the application
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new 
 SpringApplicationBuilder(ConnectionTest.class);
    builder.headless(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = builder.run(args);
}
    }
```

Class with Swing elements

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar; 
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class SpringTable1 extends JTable {
public SpringTable1(TableModel dm) {
    super(dm);
    setAutoResizeMode(AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
}

public SpringTable1() {
    setAutoResizeMode(AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
}

@Override
public void doLayout() {
    int width = getWidth();
    int columnCount = getColumnCount();
    int columnSize = width / columnCount;
    for (int index = 0; index < columnCount; index++) {
        TableColumn column = getColumnModel().getColumn(index);
        column.setResizable(true);
        column.setPreferredWidth(width);
        column.setMinWidth(100);
    }
    super.doLayout();
}

@Override
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
    return true;
}

}

@RestController
public class TLOG_Backup_Report extends JFrame {
private JButton _clickme;
private JPanel _panel;
private SpringTable1 table;
// this method is used to get TLOG status report automatically on loading 
the link.
@RequestMapping("/tlog")
public String getTlogStatusReport() throws ClassNotFoundException, 
SQLException
{   
    //Calling our inventory to get the details
    Class.forName("*****************");
    String dbURL = "**************";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    CallableStatement proc_stmt = con.prepareCall("
{********************************}");
    ResultSet rs = proc_stmt.executeQuery();
    //It creates and displays the table
    table = new SpringTable1(buildTableModel(rs));
    // Closes the Connection
    table.setSize(1000, 1000);
    table.setRowHeight(40);
    setVisible(true); 
    setResizable(true); 
    setTitle("Table");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    setSize(1000,1000);
    _panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return "Results are displayed ";

    }
   //to build the structure of the table
   public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs) throws 
   SQLException {

ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
// names of columns
Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
    columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
}
// data of the table
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
    for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
        vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
    }
    data.add(vector);
}
return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
}
}
```

Errors:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'TLOG_Backup_Report' defined in file [C:\Users\VALSA05\Documents\share\apache-tomcat-7.0.56-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\DbConnectionStatus-0.0.4\WEB-INF\classes\connectionStatusDB\TLOG_Backup_Report.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [connectionStatusDB.TLOG_Backup_Report]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:754)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5481)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [connectionStatusDB.TLOG_Backup_Report]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.awt.HeadlessException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at connectionStatusDB.TLOG_Backup_Report.<init>(ConnectionTest.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 66 more

May 30, 2018 11:21:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\Users\VALSA05\Documents\share\apache-tomcat-7.0.56-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\DbConnectionStatus-0.0.4.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/DbConnectionStatus-0.0.4]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1670)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: You should probably change the headless mode in Tomcat itself by using `-Djava.awt.headless=false`.  If that's the case, then it's a possible duplicate of [java.awt.HeadlessException - Applet not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/445049/1915448).

Comment: Thanks a lot :))... by editing this line in catalina.bat solved my error ------------set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG% -Djava.awt.headless=false" -----------

Comment: Dont add -Djava.awt.headless=false in startup.sh, startup.bat or catalina.sh it wont help. Edit this line ------- set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%" -------------- in catalina.bat to----------- set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG% -Djava.awt.headless=false"-------------- it will solve the error.